# For what purposes is たろう used?

Tags: meaning

I am reading [Fate Zero 1](http://sai-zen-sen.jp/sa/fate-zero/works/) by [虚淵]{うろぶち}玄{げん}, this book likes using archaisms and very precise vocabulary which is challenging.

Somewhere in [the prologue](http://sai-zen-sen.jp/works/fictions/fate-zero/01/01.html) there is this line:

> その日{ひ}から、彼{かれ}は天秤{てんびん}の計{はか}り手{て}**たろう**と志{こころざし}を固{かた}めた。
>   He firmly conviced himself that from now on he will be a servant of the world's balance.

I looked up in a [dictionary](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86) and I got this:

> たろ・う
>   （ 連語 ）
>   〔過去の助動詞「た」の未然形に推量の助動詞「う」の付いたもの〕
>   活用語の連用形に接続する。ガ・ナ・バ・マ行五（四）段活用の動詞に付く場合には「だろう」となる。
>   ① 過去の事柄やすでに完了し実現した事柄についての推量・想像などの意を表す。 「その時は，さぞ困っ－・うね」 「あの人の口から出たんじゃなかったら，僕も頭から信用しなかっ－・う」
>   ②（多く上昇調のイントネーションを伴って）過去の事柄やすでに完了し実現した事柄について，相手に念を押したり同意を求めたりする気持ちを表す。 「お父さんもまだ小さかっ－・う。ちょっと怖かったよ」 「この間話し－・う，そんなことは考えない方がいいよ」

Which roughly translates to

> たろう 
>   (Compound word)
>   (Auxiliary う showing supposition/guess that binds to the unrealis form of the auxiliary た) When sticking to a strong verb ending in ga, na, ba or ma, たろう becomes だろう.
>   ① Shows guess about a situation of the past or a situation that is finished. (There is no doubt that that time it must have been troublesome) (If it was not him who said that I would have not believe it.)
>   ②  (Often with a raise of intonation) Try to convince about a past fact. (My father's still a child. That's freakin'.) (not sure about the translation: It's better not to think that this discussion has been a quiet one.)

So it's about auxiliary た and う. A quick look up leads to the fact that う is a deformation of auxialiary む according to [goo](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/17145/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%86/).

> む
>   （ 助動 ） （ ○ ・○ ・む（ん） ・む（ん） ・め ・○ ）
>   〔中古の半ば以降，発音が mu から m となり，さらに n に変わったので，後世「ん」とも書かれる〕
>   推量の助動詞。活用語の未然形に付く。
>   ① **目前にないこと，まだ実現していないことについて予想し推量する意を表す。…であるだろう。…だろう。** 「現（うつつ）にも夢にも我は思はずき古りたる君にここに逢はむとは／万葉集 2601」 「我が背子が国へましなばほととぎす鳴かむ五月（さつき）はさぶしけむかも／万葉集 3996」
>   ② 話し手自身の意志や決意を表す。…するつもりだ。…するようにしよう。 「見れど飽かぬ吉野の川の常滑（とこなめ）の絶ゆる事なくまたかへり見む／万葉集 37」 「弓矢を取り立てむとすれども，手に力もなくなりて，萎えかかりたり／竹取」
>   ③ 相手や第三者の行為を勧誘し，期待する意を表す。…してくれ。…してもらいたい。…すればよい。 「逢ひ難き君に逢へる夜（よ）ほととぎす他（あた）し時ゆは今こそ鳴かめ／万葉集 1947」 「若宮など生ひ出で給はば，さるべきついでもありなむ。命長くとこそ思ひ念ぜめ／源氏 桐壺」 「子といふものなくてありなん／徒然 6」
>   ④ （連体形を用いて）実現していないことを仮定していうのに用いる。…であるようなものなら。…としたら。 「二人して打たむには，侍りなむや／枕草子 9」 「年五十になるまで，上手に至らざらん芸をば捨つべきなり／徒然 151」
>   ⑤（連体形を用いて）実現が可能だったり予想されたりするとき，推量する形で婉曲に述べるのに用いる。 「恋しからむをりをり，取りいでて見給へ／竹取」 「これが花の咲かむ折は来むよ／更級」 〔 (1) 上代では，形容詞活用にはその古い未然形語尾「け」に付く。「大魚（おうお）よし鮪（しび）突く海人（あま）よ其（し）が離（あ）ればうら恋（こお）しけむ鮪突く鮪／古事記 下」 (2) 現代語でも文語調の文章の中に「ん」の形で用いられる。「幸多からんことを祈る」「政治家たらんとする者は」「あらん限りの力」「まさに出発せんとする時」〕

And た

> た
>   （ 助動 ） （ たろ ・○ ・た ・た ・たら ・○ ）
>   〔古語の完了の助動詞「たり」の連体形「たる」からの転。中世以降の語〕
>   動詞・形容詞・形容動詞および助動詞「れる・られる」「せる・させる」「ない」「たい」「らしい」「そうだ（様態）」「ようだ」「だ」「ます」「です」などの連用形に接続する。ただし，サ行以外の五段活用の動詞には，その音便の形に付く。また，ガ・ナ・バ・マの各行の五段活用の動詞に付く時は「だ」となる。
>   ① **動作・作用が過去の事柄であることを表す。** 「大昔，この辺一帯は海だった」 「去年，北海道に移った弟が，先月帰ってきた」
>   ② **動作・作用が完了したことを表す。** 「やっと手紙を書き終えました」 「飛行機は無事着陸した」 「日はすっかり沈んだ」
>   ③ 物事が実現することを表す。 「何年ぶりかで当地方にも雪が降った」 「一番になった人には賞品をあげる」 「シャボン玉が屋根までとんだ」
>   ④ 物事や事態の確認を表す。 「見ると，それは若いスマートな青年であった」 「国境の長いトンネルを抜けると雪国であった／雪国 康成」
>   ⑤（連体形を用いて）動作・作用がすんで，その結果が状態として存在していることを表す。てある。ている。 「壁にかけた絵」 「弟の写した写真」 「とがった鉛筆」 「整った身なり」
>   ⑥（終止形を用いて）
>   ㋐ 強い決意・断言や軽い命令などを表す。 「承知しました」 「わかった，わかった」 「邪魔になるから，そこをどいた」
>   ㋑ 疑問・質問などをもちかけることを表す。 「今度の会合は何日でした」 「上りの列車は何時だった」
>   ⑦ 仮定形「たら」は，接続助詞「ば」を伴わないで，それだけでも用いられる。
>   ㋐ 仮定条件を表す。仮にそうであるならば。もしそうなったらば。 「雨が降ったら，中止にする」 「電話があったらメモしておいてくれ」 「その本を読んだら早く返してくれ」
>   ㋑ 未来の確定条件を表す。 「春になったら暖かくなる」
>   ㋒ 遠回しに命令する意を表す。主として女性が用いる。 「早くお帰りになったら」 「後片付けだけはしといたら」

I emphasized what I think is relevant.
My question has a bit evolved since I started and I would like to know

- whether the first sense of たろう is equivalent to たでしょう?
- whether the second sense of たろう can be found in recent works (that do not try to sound ancient), if not what is an equivalent?

Comment: Unfortunately, the 〜たろう in that sentence is not an example of the dictionary entry you quoted. Rather, it's the volitional form of [〜たる (助動)](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B), which is more like the equivalent of 〜である／であろう. Your two questions are still valid though, independent of this fact.

Comment: @mirka, In this case it is just 虚淵玄 who is playing on words to sound archaic and I am not sure to understand the sentence I quoted anymore. Or at least I can grasp the nuances in it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Don't worry, your translation of the sentence is correct. For example, 善人**たろう**と決める = 善人**であろう**と決める (*decide to be a good person*)

Comment: You can tell which one it is by looking at what it attaches to.  The one from と＋ある attaches to nouns because that's what と does, and the one from て＋ある attaches to 連用形 (or 音便形 in the modern language) because that's what て does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @mirka said in the comment, this is from an archaic affirmative auxiliary verb [たり](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/139245/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A/) (≒である), not the auxiliary verb た denoting past tense. And this う denotes someone's will (as in 学校に行こ**う**). So basically it's a nuanced, literary version of 天秤の計り手であろう ("to be going to be a 計り手").

In modern usage, I think the nuance of this kind of `(職業/身分) + たる` is something like "behave properly as X", "a good X", "qualify as X", etc., as described in [this entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/139292/meaning/m0u/):

> 《文語の断定の助動詞「たり」の連体形》
>   １ 資格を表す。…であるところの。「学生**たる**もの、勉強すべきである」

学生たるもの勉強すべき roughly means "A *(good)* student should study".

Xたろう is not very common, but one can say, for example, （困難な状況で）紳士たろうとする, which means "to try to behave properly as a gentleman".