# What is the function of たろ in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I found this sentence while I was practicing in Wanikani platform.

「ドタマかち割って脳みそストローでチューチュー吸うたろか！」とお化けは怒って言った。

Translation according to Wanikani: "Do you want me to crack your skull open and suck out your brains with a straw?" the ghost said angrily.

There is a たろ in there and I have not yet been able to decipher its meaning. Would you be so kind as to give me a clue? I'd really appreciate it if you did so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole quoted line is in Kansai colloquial speech (and the translation provided is good).

「吸{す}うたろか」 is 「吸ってやろうか」 in Standard "dictionary" Japanese, meaning "***should I suck ~~?***".  It is the volitional form of 「吸ってやる」 with a question marker 「か」.

「ドタマ」 is the tough guy's slang for 「頭{あたま}」.

「かち割{わ}る」 is an emphatic version of  「割る」 or 「ふたつに割る」.

「チューチュー」 is the onomatopoeia for the sucking sound.  It is a regular onomatopoeia that is used everywhere.

Comment: So, this たろ doesn't have anything to do with the explanation given in this link: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29356/for-what-purposes-is-たろう-used?